# xml конфигурация Log4J

Tags: java, log4j

Здавствуйте, имеется xml файл с таким содержанием:

```
<Configuration>
<Appenders>
    <File name="file" fileName="log.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}: %L %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="file" level="INFO"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Где сохранится лог - файл, может надо указывать путь?

Comment: Лог сохранится рядом  с запускаемым файлом Где конкретно зависит от того это JAR или WAR. Надо указывать полный путь, или использовать плэйсхолдеры и переменные окружения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментарии сказано почти верно по факту но не раскрыто по смыслу.

Есть "рабочий каталог", от которого строятся все относительные пути. По умолчанию он совпадает с каталогом в котором находится jar и происходит его запуск. Но на самом деле он может быть любым.

Узнать его программно можно так:

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Задать его можно с помощью опции `-Duser.dir`. Таким образом можно запустить одни jar несколько раз из разных каталогов с разными настройками.